# Python 3.8 module duplication and app object scope within imported functions

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'm confused about import of custom modules. As you can see in the code below, in main I first import all libraries needed by everything AND that I duplicated those imports in my i_setup_functions.py file. Leaving any of them out of either file created errors. Same with duplication of "app = Flask(**name**)". I really hope that redundancy is not correct and there is some simple way to fix this. All I want to do is include setup for sessions, email, data connection, etc. Only showing sessions here for simplicity sake.

BTW: The entire app worked bug-free until I tried to modularize.

Error message:

```
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

That error message points to a line in a function in the middle of main.py that tries to create a session.

Thanks for any ideas you all can share!

main.py:

```
from flask import session
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from i_setup_functions import setup_sessions

app = Flask(__name__)
# is the following line even necessary in either module?
application = app

setup_sessions()
setup_mail()
setup_logging()
[snip]
# Error here:
​session["id_user"] = id_user
```

i_setup_functions.py

```
from flask import session
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from i_setup_functions import setup_sessions

app = Flask(__name__)
application = app

def setup_sessions():
    random.seed(datetime.now())
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = str(random.randint(1, 500)) + "jibber" + str(random.randint(1, 500)) + "jabber"
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=30)
    return True
```

Comment: Have you tried making `setup_sessions()` take `app` as a parameter, instead of making it a file-level variable, and then passing `app` into it in `main.py` when you call `setup_sessions()`? You shouldn't need to assign `application` at all, unless you just want to be able to access the variable with either name.

Comment: That worked! AND taught me another thing about Python. Thank you!

Comment: Any ideas on how the interpreter seems to want me to import the same libraries in main.py and i_setup_functions.py? How do I get around that? Seems too redundant to be correct. Should I ask this as a separate/new stack question?

Comment: If you need to directly refer to the module, then you need to import the module in the same file. Don't worry about importing the same module in two different files - python is smart, and both imports will point to the same loaded object in memory (the module is only ever loaded once, even if imported in many different files). The point is clarity - if I'm looking at one file, I should be able to know _where_ every single function comes from, without having to look at the rest of the program (in contrast to, say, C/C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two (or more?) separate apps and setting the `SECRET_KEY` to the one that isn't serving your application.

To fix this remove all `app = Flask(__name__)` calls from all modules except `main.py`. Then, pass the `app` you create in `main.py` to all the places you need it.

```py
from flask import session
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from i_setup_functions import setup_sessions

app = Flask(__name__)

setup_sessions(app)
setup_mail(app)
setup_logging(app)

[snip]

​session["id_user"] = id_user
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked! Any ideas on how the interpreter *seems* to want me to import the same libraries in main.py *and* i_setup_functions.py? How do I get around that? Seems too redundant to be correct.

Comment: How does it _want_ you to import them? Does it show a warning or an error? I'm not sure I understand the issue.